# Как сохранить функцию в local storage?

Tags: javascript, функции, localstorage

Возникла заминка при работе с Local Storage, есть объект с переменными вида:

```
var Data = {
    ccurrentFunction: null,
    Name: "Павлик",
    crank: "Начинающий",
    cday: 1,
    ctime: 5,
};
```

В этот объект данные перезаписываются, а потом извлекаются при необходимости. Особенно важно свойство `currentFunction`.

В него сохраняется имя функции, которая будет вызываться при загрузке.

Вот пример:

```
function training(){
    currentFunction = training;
    // код JS
};
```

В объект передаётся имя функции:

```
Data.ccurrentFunction = currentFunction;
```

Далее просто перемещаем сформированный объект в Local Storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('savedata', JSON.stringify(Data));
```

В итоге объект сохраняется в хранилище, но без `currentFunction`, остальные есть.

Т.е. имя функции, воспринимаемое как функция, не преобразовывается в строку и вообще не записывается в хранилище.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно передать имя функции в хранилище, чтобы потом извлечь его и вызвать.

Спасибо!

Comment: Сохраните как строку. `currentFunction = 'training';`. Либо используйте костыль toSource() и запишите содержимое функции ( Лучше не надо)

Comment: Если нужно имя фукнции как строка, можно использовать `currentFunction.name`. См. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что происходит при преобразовании объекта в строку и обратно:

```js
const func1 = () => {
  console.log("функция")
}

const obj = {
  boolean: true,
  string: "строка",
  number: 12345,
  nul: null,
  undfd: undefined,
  inf: Infinity,
  date: new Date(),
  func1,
  func2: func1,
  func3: "func1"
}

const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

console.log(newObj)
// {
//  "boolean": true,
//  "string": "строка",
//  "number": 12345,
//  "nul": null,
//  "inf": null,
//  "date": "2020-08-28T22:06:14.982Z",
//  "func3": "func1"
// }
```

если Вы используете в нем структуры данных `Map`, `Set`, классы типа `Date`, `Infinity`, `undefined`, функции, типизированные массивы и др.

Самым простым вариантом будет записывать название функции в объект как строку:

```
func3: "func1"
```

и далее работать уже с ней.

Comment: Спасибо. В целом всё ясно. Сделал следующим образом сохранил отдельно функцию целиком, таким образом: 
localStorage.setItem('savename', currentFunction);
Сохранилась вся функция строкой. Затем преобразовал с помощью eval, таким образом:
var loadFunc = localStorage.getItem('savename');
loadFunc = eval('(' + loadFunc + ')');
loadFunc ();
Правда с одной вложенной функцией начались проблемы. Но тут уже другая история.

Comment: @ExtraCamelot, странно, что проблемы всего с одной ... всё еще впереди

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov Вы правы. В итоге эта одна потащила за собой другие. Этот способ не работает, если проект разбит на несколько файлов. Если в одном, то всё в порядке.